# Reference Error after deployed -webpackJsonp is not defined

Tags: angular, npm

using Angular 4 application, while running sample in development mode it working fine bur after deployment facing webpackJsonp not defined issue most of the time.

This is my bundle creation:  index.html file

[image]

This is my package json

> `{
>     "name": "my-request",
>     "version": "0.0.0",
>     "license": "MIT",
>     "scripts": {
>         "ng":"ng",
>         "start":"ng serve",
>         "build":"ng build",
>         "test":"ng test",
>         "lint":"ng lint",
>         "e2e":"ng e2e"
>     },
>     "private": true,
>     "dependencies": {
>       "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
>       "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
>       "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
>       "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
>       "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
>       "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
>       "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
>       "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
>       "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
>       "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
>       "core-js": "^2.4.1",
>       "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
>       "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
>       "ngx-pagination": "^3.1.1",
>       "rxjs": "^5.5.12",
>       "web-animation-js": "^2.3.1",
>       "xlsx": "^0.13.1",
>       "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
>     },
>     "devDependencies": {
>       "@angular/cli": "1.6.6",
>       "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
>       "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
>       "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
>       "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
>       "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
>       "codelyzer": "~4.0.1",
>       "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
>       "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
>       "karma": "~1.7.0",
>       "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
>       "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
>       "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
>       "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
>       "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
>       "protractor": "~5.1.2",
>       "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
>       "tslint": "~5.7.0",
>       "typescript": "~3.5.2"
>     }
>   }`

Comment: webpackJsonp is not defined usually mean you are not loading the javascript bundles in the right order. They must be loaded in the order present in the index.html that the CLI generates.

I hope that helps you solving the problem :)

Comment: ok thanks.. do u have any order preferences...any reference will help @sevic

Comment: no sorry, in doubt try and error :/

Answer (score 0):

Try validating the sources of these scripts , during development the links work but when you build the project structure is changed a little, the best way would be to place all the scripts, css and images resouces in the assets folder and change your source urls to get file from assets folder.

```
<script src="assets/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
```